# Do groups in h5py preserve the order in which its members were added?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

The [h5py docs say that](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/group.html#Group.keys) `group.keys()` returns the group's members as a list in python 2, and as a set-like view in python3.

In either case, can I assume that when iterating through `group.keys()`, I'll iterate through them in the order in which the members were originally added to the group?

Answer (score 2):

My advice is: unless the documentation explicitely states that the returned collection is ordered, don't rely on it. The fact that a set is returned in Python3 strongly indicates that the keys are not ordered — or that any order is accidental.